# add get parameter to helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, helper

I added the following line in config/routes.rb file :

```
get '/movies/similar', :contoller => 'movies', :action => 'similar'
```

I see that there is a helper method with name `'movies_similar_path'`. I want to add a get parameter to `'movies_similar_path'` with name 'director' so I can get `'/movies/similar?director=someone'`

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to define parameter in the helper, you can assign it in the `link_to`.

```
link_to "Similar", movies_similar_path(:director => @director.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. noticed the typo in 'controller' in your routes line?
2. What you want, you do in the form of page you are calling by adding a hidden field, or putting the extra fields in the 'link_to'. Like "link_to "simsforthisdirector", movies_similar_path(@movie), :director=>@director.name
   See: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to
   Especially the examples will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails 3 then you can declare route as -

```
get '/movies/similar(/:director)', :to => 'movies#similar'
```

and while using you can use it as -

```
movies_similar_path
```

or

```
movies_similar_path(@director.name)
```